# Setting the Ember root URL without redirection

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-router

Let's say my `Router` looks like this:

```
Bananas.Router.map ->
  @resource "bananas", ->
    @route 'index', path: '/'
```

and my `BananasIndexRoute` looks like this:

```
Bananas.BananasIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) -> 
    controller.set("content", [ "baby", "manzano", "burro", "plantain", "red" ])
```

Manipulating the bananas belongs in the `BananaController`, but when the user visits  `waytomanybananas.com`, I'd like they to be able to interact with my application. Currently, I'm accomplishing this by redirecting the user to the bananas path like this:

```
Bananas.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  redirect: -> @transitionTo("bananas")
```

However, I'd prefer to have the the application render the `bananas` route when I visit the root URL (the equivilent of `root` in Rails). What's the best way to accomplish this using Ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `path` to your resource:

```
Bananas.Router.map ->
    @resource 'bananas', { path: '/' }, ->
```

Comment: idk what you're doing or trying to do. this should work

Comment: my ember serve was getting dirty somehow or not keeping up with actual changes, despite saving, and restarting the server. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

this would do it

```
Bananas.Router.map ->
  @resource "bananas", path: '/'
```

Comment: When I originally read this, I read `@route` as `@resource`. I think @MilkyWayJoe's answer is the way to go, but thanks anyway.